# Creating Tables and triggers using SSDT tools in visual studio

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

When we create a table in visual studio using ssdt we do not have to execute it separately. But while creating trigger on some table we need to execute it before building the project. why? and 
P.S: When we create trigger along with table definition we do not have to execute it. But i want to add the script of many triggers for different tables in same file.

Comment: Why would you want to add many triggers to the same file for different tables?  This seems a really silly thing to do to me, the whole point of the db proj in vs is to allow you to separate your scripts i.e triggers  etc into separate files, that and the ability to easily publish and compare schemas.  Combining them into one file will just lead to maintenance hell in my opinion, its completely counter productive.

Comment: I agree with @zeencat, you are better structuring the project so that each table has its own folder and all the triggers for it live in that folder in separate files (let's forget using triggers should generally be avoided anyway for now)

Comment: @ankit - what do you mean by "we need to execute it before building the project"? If you define the trigger correctly there should be no problem building it - I think there's a misunderstanding about what your issue is based on this.